# LaTeX in column names of a table in R markdown

Tags: r, gt

How can I have LaTeX symbols like alpha or delta in column names of html output with `gt` package.

```
library(gt)

# Create a data frame
data <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3),
  y = c(4, 5, 6)
)

# Set the column names as LaTeX formulas
colnames(data) <- c("$\\alpha$", "$\\beta$")

# Create a gt table
gt(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not mind using unicode, this works but I appreciate it does not use LaTeX equation mode.

```
library(gt)

# Create a data frame
data <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3),
  y = c(4, 5, 6)
)

# Set the column names with unicode
colnames(data) <- c("\u03B1", "\u03B2")

# Create a gt table
gt(data)
```

[image]

Comment: This pretty much answers my question. Although I was hoping for a version with full formula support.

Comment: @Marco, using rmarkdown in a `.Rdm` file `colnames(data) <- c("$\\alpha$", "$\\beta$")` and  `knitr::kable(data)` achieves the required appearance; but I'm not sure that would answer the question.

Comment: This approach also worked with the `modelsummary` package, but not with `gt`. Is there a way to convert `gt` to `kable`? There is a `as_kable()` function in `gtsummary`.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know, It might be worth checking out the gt github site: https://github.com/rstudio/gt which includes related packages.

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not find a solution with the `gt` package, I switched to `modelsummary` and `datasummary_df()`. Another great package that produces html output in markdown files. It can take full `LaTeX` syntax.

```
library(modelsummary)

# Create a data frame
data <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3),
  y = c(4, 5, 6)
)

# Set the column names as LaTeX formulas
colnames(data) <- c("$\\alpha + \\overline{x}$", "$\\beta$")

datasummary_df(data)
```

[image]